# Installing newest PPA driver for Nvidia (410) leads to black screen

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, ppa

So after some trial and error I settled on installing the nvidia drivers via the ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-410
```

410 is the current live branch on the website: https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa and I'm also running an RTX 2080 so its the only version that supports my GPU.

The install completed successfully, and then I rebooted. I reboot to runlevel 3 because I saw that this is the right thing to do when installing graphics drivers. Then to start x:

```
sudo init 5
```

Now X starts, the screen lights up and the login window appears. I put my password in - then the screen goes dark.

Any ideas on what I should do to be able to fully log into X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the most reliable procedure I found to install NVidia drivers on Ubuntu 18.04.

1. Download the latest here: https://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html
2. Set the driver file to be executable.
3. Switch to terminal: ctrl+alt+F3
4. kill GDM:  sudo service gdm3 stop OR sudo service gdm stop
5. run the installer: sudo ./Nvidia….bin
6. ignore the fail in the pre-check.
7. ignore the updated libsvm (spelling error) library
8. If you are running the 64 bit OS, ignore 32 bit library fail
9. update GDM configuration automatically.

Restart your computer and enjoy. Unfortunately, it seems that this procedures has to be periodically repeated with Ubuntu updates.