# Black screen after installing NVIDIA drivers 390, 410, 415 for GeForce 1050 TI

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

#### Problem

I cannot get my NVIDIA 1050 TI to work with Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10 (I updated, same issues). Every time I switch from the built-in drivers to the ones from `ppa:graphics-drivers`, a reboot will lead to a black screen, from which I can't get anywhere.

I always have to boot into recovery mode, purge the `nvidia` packages, and try again. My monitor is connected to the DP port on the NVIDIA card; it's an AOC 4K 60Hz display.

I have tried the following versions of the NVIDIA drivers via `apt`:

- 396
- 410
- 415

**Update:** The problem is not GDM3 or lightdm (I've tried both), it's actually that the screen where I get asked the LUKS password is not shown. When I  type my password blindly, I can continue to the login screen!

#### Related questions / discussions

I have seen the following posts:

- [Installing NVIDIA GEFORCE 1050 TI - Cannot Get To GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004927/installing-nvidia-geforce-1050-ti-cannot-get-to-gui) — but with the built-in driver, the graphics card works. It's only when switching to the third-party drivers that the issue occurs.
- [NVIDIA drivers 410 break Ubuntu 18.04 with GTX 1050](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088805/nvidia-drivers-410-break-ubuntu-18-04-gtx-1050) — doing this at least gets me to the screen where I can enter my LUKS password (albeit with the wrong display resolution), and it then proceeds to the Ubuntu logo, but the progress stops at three of five dots. Just uncommenting `WaylandEnable` gets me a black screen only, so it's probably the `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` that changes… something.
- [Black screen after install Nvidia Driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/909731/black-screen-after-install-nvidia-driver)
- [Black screen after reinstall/install nvidia driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045004/black-screen-after-reinstall-install-nvidia-driver)
- [Installing newest PPA driver for Nvidia (410) leads to black screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086538/installing-newest-ppa-driver-for-nvidia-410-leads-to-black-screen) — I cannot even get to the login window

Some bug reports:

- [A bug report here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/1773113) about the 410 drivers just leading to a black screen, without resolution
- [Another one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/1752053) which was closed without resolution
- [This one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1705369) seems to be relevant,

Any idea what I could look for? Where would I find logs that give me an indication of the error?

#### More info

Detailed info about the device:

```
➜ lspci | grep -i vga
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] (rev a1)
```

The problem is the same on both 4.15 and 4.18 kernels (18.04, 18.10). My current kernel:

```
Linux voltaire 4.18.0-13-generic #14-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 09:04:24 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My `apt-cache policy`:

```
linux-headers-generic:
  Installed: 4.18.0.13.14
  Candidate: 4.18.0.13.14
  Version table:
 *** 4.18.0.13.14 500
        500 http://ubuntu.inode.at/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ubuntu.inode.at/ubuntu cosmic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.18.0.10.11 500
        500 http://ubuntu.inode.at/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
```

Output I get when installing the latest `nvidia-driver-415` package:

```
Loading new nvidia-415.25 DKMS files...
Building for 4.18.0-13-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.18.0-13-generic
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Done.

nvidia:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.18.0-13-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-modeset.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.18.0-13-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-drm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.18.0-13-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-uvm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.18.0-13-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
Setting up nvidia-driver-415 (415.25-0ubuntu0~gpu18.10.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.131ubuntu15) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-13-generic
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the dkms modules succeeds in building? Could you also add output of `lspci | grep -i vga`

Comment: is this a desktop or laptop? you could look at eg. output from when you installed it. Or you could do something like this: `sudo updatedb && locate nvidia.ko`

Comment: For instance when running `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-415` it will show somthing like `nvidia-uvm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-43-generic/kernel/drivers/char/drm/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.`

Comment: That would make sense.  Could you also add output of `uname -a` and `apt-cache policy linux-headers-generic` before installing drivers?

Comment: @AndersF.U.Kiær Updated my post. Unfortunately, the same issue. Any idea where I could find a log? The interesting thing is that the black screen already occurs before the prompt for the LUKS password.

Comment: Try the solution I posted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load the proprietary Nvidia drivers from initramfs.

`/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`

```
# List of modules that you want to include in your initramfs.
# They will be loaded at boot time in the order below.
#
# Syntax:  module_name [args ...]
#
# You must run update-initramfs(8) to effect this change.
#
# Examples:
#
# raid1
# sd_mod
nvidia
nvidia-drm
nvidia-modeset
nvidia-uvm
```

You could also check the content of `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf`, should be something like this:

```
options nvidia-drm modeset=1
blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off
```

Make sure to update initramfs.
`sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`

To work around bug with still black screen on typing password, try the following:
edit `/etc/default/grub`
change the two lines to be like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

apply it with running `sudo update-grub`

Reboot, and hopefully enjoy!

Comment: I have no such nvidia entries in the modules file, and there is no file from nvidia in modprobe.d after installing the `nvidia-driver-415` package. Or are you saying that I have to manually load the entries in the modules file? Shouldn't that be done automatically?

Comment: I got one step further. The black screen is only shown when I have to type in my LUKS password. Once I type it in blindly, I can continue to the login screen!

Comment: Seems to be this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-367/+bug/1638983

Comment: Did you create the file? and modified the initramfs module list? i assume yes? then you could do some changes to grub and you should be set. All you need to work around that bug is to remove splash and quiet from grub. check updated answer.

Comment: I did not create the `modules` file – it was already present. Nor did I modify it, as I assumed that if the entries were *really* needed, they'd already be there. Since the NVIDIA drivers work fine after typing in the LUKS password, I assume no changes are needed in these files? I'll check the GRUB options tomorrow. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: I am confused, can you tell me which modifications you did and did not do?

Comment: I did not do any modifications. I just installed the drivers again, typed the password blindly, and it worked.

Comment: Ok to clearify it. The addition in modules file is really needed for the initramfs to have your graphicdriver. It is the initramfs that show the screen where you decrypt your drive.  GRUB options should not be necessary, but is nice to change because you get a clue about what is happening :)

Comment: It worked! I tried both empty options for GRUB as well as `nomodeset`. The resolution is wrong, but I don't care at this point. I have yet to try the other additions you mentioned.

Comment: To get the resolution you want for boot you will actually have to use modeset => options nvidia-drm modeset=1, but it will only work if the driver is available at initramfs.